# Azure database file location

Tags: azure

There is Azure SQL server with name xxxdb10.database.windows.net that is up and running. I am trying to create DB there and I have to use specifics application in order to have proper DB structure. Everything works with SQL Server Express as you can see below, program add file location automatically. But when I try to point to Azure SQL server and do the same application does not recognizance path and I got this error below. What to use for database file location in case of Azure SQL server please, can you help?

With SQL Server Express:

[image]

With Azure SQL server:

[image]

Comment: This may help: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/design-first-database-tutorial

Answer (score 0, accepted):

•   I would suggest you use Microsoft SSMS (SQL Server Management Studio) tool to connect to the Azure SQL Server created in Azure instead of SQL Express. Since SSMS is only a tool for managing various types of SQL Databases locally or in Azure, thus it should be promptly used for creating such Azure databases. Please refer the link below on detailed documentation and information regarding this as well as refer to the snapshots depicting the usage of SSMS as a prompt tool for connecting to Azure SQL databases and server.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/connect-query-ssms

[image: SSMS-Connect]
[image: DB Connection]
[image: New Database]
[image: DB expansion]
[image: Azure DB]

In the above snapshots, you can see that we can connect to an Azure SQL Server and creating a database in it through SSMS.